# Python date conversion functions (similar to SAS date functions) running slowly

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, python-datetime

I've recently been testing out some sas date functions that I've written for python and although they work as expected, the runtime on them is far too long (I'm working with datasets of 10+ million rows and 1000+ columns). Is there any way for me to retain the functionality but decrease the runtime?

**Test Data:**

```
# Import Packages
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

# Define lists of dates
obs_date_list = ["202107" + str(np.random.randint(10,31)) for i in range(10000000)]
out_date_list = ["202108" + str(np.random.randint(10,30)) for i in range(10000000)]

# Create Test DataFrame
df = pd.DataFrame({"obs":obs_date_list, "out":out_date_list}, columns = ["obs", "out"])
```

**Intck:**

Return the number of months difference between the two given dates

```
def intck_month(obs, out):
    
    diff = -1
    
    if (out < obs) or pd.isna(obs) or pd.isna(out):
        return diff
    elif obs == out:
        diff = 0
        return diff
    else:
        diff = 12*((dt.datetime.strptime(out, '%Y%m%d').year) - (dt.datetime.strptime(obs, '%Y%m%d').year)) + \
                ((dt.datetime.strptime(out, '%Y%m%d').month) - (dt.datetime.strptime(obs, '%Y%m%d').month))
        return diff
```

Test

```
df["diff"] = np.vectorize(intck_month)(df["obs"], df["out"])
```

Runtime

```
4min 25s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

**Intnx:**

Return the date (either the beginning or end of the month) after incrementing by given number of months

```
def intnx_month(date, increment, alignment):
    
    out_date = ""
    
    if pd.isna(date):
        return out_date
    elif alignment == "B":
        out_date = dt.datetime.strptime(str((pd.Timestamp(date) + pd.offsets.MonthBegin(increment)).date()), '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y%m%d')
        return out_date
    elif alignment == "E":
        out_date = dt.datetime.strptime(str((pd.Timestamp(date) + pd.offsets.MonthEnd(increment)).date()), '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y%m%d')
        return out_date
```

Test

```
df["out_inc"] = np.vectorize(intnx_month)(df["out"], 1, "B")
```

Runtime

```
5min 18s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

**Increment Date:**

Increment the date by the specified number of months (any dates which have days left over after incrementing, e.g. incrementing 31st Jan 2021 by 1 month, will have their dates aligned to the end of the month, so in this example we would get 28th Feb 2021.

```
def increment_date(date, increment):
    
    out_date = ""
    
    if pd.isna(date):
        return out_date
    else:
        out_date = dt.datetime.strptime(str((pd.Timestamp(date) + pd.DateOffset(months = increment)).date()), '%Y-%m-%d').strftime('%Y%m%d')
        return out_date
```

Test

```
df["obs_inc"] = np.vectorize(increment_date)(df["obs"], 3)
```

Runtime

```
7min 48s ± 0 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 1 run, 1 loop each)
```

Comment: Use `pd.Timestamp`, `pd.Timedelta`, and `pd.offsets`

Comment: `pandas` has its own vectorized datetime operations What is the goal here? There may be a more straightforward or ("pandas") was to accomplish whatever it is.

Comment: @HenryEcker I have various different date columns that I pass through these functions (after which I perform other operations on the results, e.g. drop rows whose dates are more than a set number of months apart). They are functions purely so that I can call them at different points in my code and not be worried about typos or inconsistencies, but I'm open to suggestions/alternatives.

Comment: `np.vectorize` is not a performance tool.  It is still running python `date` function separately for each row.